# Symfony 2.8: How to dynamically set database params based on the hostname

Tags: php, symfony

I've 100 third-level domains pointing all to the same server, where I have a Symfony 2.8 project. I need Symfony to be able to connect to different databases, depending on the third-level domain.

I know I can create as many environment I want, but the sintax for the environment is more like:
 - domainname.com/app_customer1.php/[..]
 - domainname.com/app_customer2.php/[..]
 - domainname.com/app_customer3.php/[..]

White I would like this URL structure:
 - customer1.domainname.com/[..]
 - customer2.domainname.com/[..]
 - customer3.domainname.com/[..]

On a different Laravel 5 project I've been able to do the trick. How do you suggest to handle this in Symfony 2.8?

Thanks,
Guido

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem :) And maybe vote it if you think it's a good answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `database_name` depending on the host like this:

```
// app/config/parameters.php
<?php

$dbName = 'default'; // For CLI

if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
    $dbName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}

$container->setParameter('database_name', $dbName);
```

Config:

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    # ...
    - { resource: parameters.php }

doctrine:
    # ...
    dbal:
        # ...
        dbname: "%database_name%"
```

But it will not work in CLI, so if you can implement the trick used in Laravel to define your condition-based database name (or any other parameter), it could be nice.

Comment: Dear Chalasr, using it I found that Symfony caches the config params used the first time Symfony gets loaded after the last cache:clear. This means that if I clear the cache and then I visit db1.mysite.it it correctly loads params for db1, but if after that I visit db2.mysite.it it keeps considering (because of its cache) the db1 params! So, it's not possible to adopt this strategy!